FBAR reporting for accounts held for a part of the previous year
I should know the answer to this but (obviously) don't even though I have been filing FBAR for a few years. This is a new situation this year --
Do I have to include accounts that I held for only a part of the year? For example, if I  started a CD at a new bank in Feb 2023 and closed the CD in May 2023, so now that account has 0 balance (as of 31 Dec 2023 as well as currently), do I have to include it in the FBAR report?
What if I actually closed the CD-bearing account in May once the CD matured so that it no longer exists? Do I still have to include it in the FBAR report?
I searched the FBAR docs but they don't seem to indicate anything on this specific subject.

The FBAR asks for the maximum account value, so even if the account balance is now 0, you still report the highest balance it had during the year.

thanks… and what if I closed the account after withdrawing all the money so that the account doesn't exist anymore (even though it did for a part of the year)?

@punkish: You would still report it

Not only you still need to report it, but if you transferred the balance to another account you'll report the highest balance on both effectively reporting the same amounts on multiple accounts.
